# jQuery: converting document on click function to inline onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

due to some circumstances, i have to convert my click function to a separate function and call that function using inline `onClick="myFunction();"`

My current code is like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.exBtn', function(){
var ex = $(this).attr('data-ex');
$('.btnsHolderEx').hide();
$('.subbtnsHolder').show();

$('.pageDivEx').addClass('width', '100%');

});
```

I tried this but this is not right:

```
 function myFunction(e) {

    var ex = e.attr('data-ex');
    $('.btnsHolderEx').hide();
    $('.subbtnsHolder').show();

    $('.pageDivEx').addClass('width', '100%');

}
```

could someone please advice on this?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my simplified code:

```js
//ex Btns////
function exFunction(e) {
    var ex = e.attr('data-ex');
 
 alert(ex);

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="exBtn" onClick="exFunction" data-ex="test 1">
  test 1
</div>

<div class="exBtn" onClick="exFunction();" data-ex="test 2">
  test 2
</div>


<div class="exBtn" onClick="exFunction" data-ex="test 3">
  test 3
</div>
```

Comment: How do you know "it's not right"? Do you get an error? And, show us the relevant HTML and CSS so that we can replicate your issue.

Comment: you are using the event itself, instead of the element. use `e.target.attr`

Comment: @ScottMarcus, added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `e` is not the same thing as `$(this)`. Try this:

```
 function myFunction(e) {
    var ex = $(e.target).attr('data-ex');
    $('.btnsHolderEx').hide();
    $('.subbtnsHolder').show();
    $('.pageDivEx').addClass('width', '100%');
 }
```

Also, when you create the `onclick` event, make sure you add the `event` param inline:

```
<div class="exBtn" onClick="exFunction(event)" data-ex="test 1">
  test 1
</div>
```

Finally, if you are accessing `data` attributes, use the `data` keyword in jQuery.

Here is a short example:

```js
exFunction = function(e) {
    var ex = $(e.target).data('ex');
    alert(ex);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="exBtn" onClick="exFunction(event)" data-ex="test 1">
  test 1
</div>

<div class="exBtn" onClick="exFunction(event)" data-ex="test 2">
  test 2
</div>


<div class="exBtn" onClick="exFunction(event)" data-ex="test 3">
  test 3
</div>
```

Comment: i get this erro: TypeError: e is undefined

Comment: Sorry, @DavidHope, it's been too long since I've done an inline handler. I forgot you have to add the `event` param into the inline definition. Check my updated answer. It also contains a working example.

Comment: It is not certain that `e.target` will always be the right element. OP will probalbly have some inner elements inside his `div`... And then, the clicked element could be a child.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, you are correct. but I moved my data-ex attribute to the inner element now.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette is correct. It works for now, but if you ever want to extend your functionality, you may consider using some sort of identifier and/or class structure to query your DOM objects.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the element from the inline call.

```
onClick="myFunction(this);"
```

Then use it to look up the element using jQuery, by wrapping it with `$()`.

```
function myFunction(element) {

  //var ex = $(element).attr('data-ex');  // this will get the attribute's value as onload

  // An alternative:
  var ex = $(element).data('ex');  // This will get the current attribute's value even if it changed after page load

  $('.btnsHolderEx').hide();
  $('.subbtnsHolder').show();

  //$('.pageDivEx').addClass('width', '100%');  // ?? That's wrong.

  // You probably wish to do this instead:
  $('.pageDivEx').css({'width':'100%'});

}
```

Here is a snippet:

```js
//ex Btns////
function exFunction(element) {
  var ex = $(element).data('ex');

  alert(ex);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="exBtn" onclick="exFunction(this);" data-ex="test 1">
  test 1
</div>

<div class="exBtn" onclick="exFunction(this);" data-ex="test 2">
  test 2
</div>

<div class="exBtn" onclick="exFunction(this);" data-ex="test 3">
  test 3
</div>
```

Comment: I get undefined when i alert(ex);

Comment: Is the `onclick` attribute on the same element where the `data-ex` is?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed.

Comment: Have a look at this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/wpBYMQ)

Answer (score 1):

taking the answer of everyone and updating your jsfiddle
you have `onClick` when should be `onclick` and you have to pass `this` as parameter so that way you are passing the element clicked here is your jsfiddle updated and the codepen working good from Louys

https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/wpBYMQ

https://jsfiddle.net/obuh9bfk/2/